# ng-repeat is not working to refresh the display results based on filter search

Tags: html, angularjs, google-sheets, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

// My ng-repeat is displaying the results fine, but after typing in the search box it is not filtering results as per search. please help. Also, I'm getting data from http.get
   // I'm new to angular js can you help how to repeat search results and display nothing when you don't enter anything in search box. 
   // I used ng-show this is helping initially to stop showing
    topic and response are my column headers in sheet

```
           <html>
    <head>


<script src="menu.js"></script>      
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Json file : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/public/basic?alt=json

// code for displaying the data in tabs
 // Json file : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/public/basic?alt=json

function openPage(pageName,elmnt) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.color = "#969595";

  }

  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.color = "white";

}


    //angular js code to display search in JSON URL data

   var app= angular.module('sample', []);
 app.controller('sampleController', function ($scope, $http) {              
   var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/od6/public/values?alt=json";
     //var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/2/public/values?alt=json";
     //var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/3/public/values?alt=json";
    //var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1OJX_UfZ7KQ-NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/1/public/values?alt=json"; // url for sheet1

    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {     
         $scope.users = data.feed.entry;
         //console.log($scope.users);
    })
    .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(status);
         console.log("Error occured");
    }); 
   app.filter('highlightFilter', $sce =>
 function (element, searchInput) {
   element = element.replace(new RegExp(`(${searchInput})`, 'gi'),
             '<span class="highlighted">$&</span>');
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(element);
 });
    $scope.search='';
    $scope.searchFilter=function(item){

        if(item.gsx$topic.$t.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.gsx$response.$t.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        // code to highlight

      // code to highlight
        return true;

            }
      return false;
    }

});   


</script>


    </head>
<body>


<div ng-app="sample"  ng-controller="sampleController">



  <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search in all sheets" ></input>

    <br>
    <br>
  <table  style="border: 1px solid black ;" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:blue; font-size:14px;"><center><b>Question</b></center></td>
            <td style="color:blue; font-size:14px;"><center><b>Response</b></center></td>
        </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchFilter">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:30%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$topic.$t}}</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:70%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$response.$t}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see a $ in your search input box's ng-model. Remove that and try please

Comment: Hi Risalat, I tried this already but not working. Can you suggest any

Comment: can someone help to highlight the search word display in yellow color higlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add search filter on single field from $scope.users then you have to specify that property from json

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter: { gsx$topic.$t : search}">
```

also please update input for modal as :

```html
<input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="search" ng-click="didSelectLanguage()"></input>
```

Comment: Hi Snehal, I tried with your filter suggestion and removing $ it is not working. can you please let me know any other suggestion

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bjqsgfzc/1/) Can you check this. i hope it will work

Comment: Hi Snehal, Thanks a lot It is working. The only problem is 1. It is giving an exact match, even if we enter small letters that should match with starting capital letters also 2. Can we highlight the search text with a yellow color in the display results? Please help!

Comment: Hi @Snehal S, 2. Can we highlight the search text with a yellow color in the display results? Please help!. I resolved the exact match issue using toLowerCases().

Comment: can I exclude <h3> Heading </h3> and display when only the results appear from that div on search